# Array index from first to second last in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, powershell

How can I get the array element range of first to second last?

For example,

```
$array = 1,2,3,4,5
$array[0] - will give me the first (1)
$array[-2] - will give me the second last (4)
$array[0..2] - will give me first to third (1,2,3)
$array[0..-2] - I'm expecting to get first to second last (1,2,3,4) but I get 1,5,4 ???
```

I know I can do long hand and go `for($x=0;$x -lt $array.count;$x++)`, but I was looking for the square bracket shortcut.

Comment: You could just do `$array[0..($array.length-2)]`.

Comment: Robert's suggestion is unfortunately the best way I know of.  I too wanted $array[0..-2] to behave as you expected it to. But no, it indexes backwards 0 -> [len-1] -> [len - 2].  I really don't see how that is useful at all.

Comment: @robert.westerlund You should add your comment as an answer so we can close this question :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You just need to calculate the end index, like so:

```
$array[0..($array.length - 2)]
```

Do remember to check that you actually have more than two entries in your array first, otherwise you'll find yourself getting duplicates in the result.

An example of such a duplicate would be:

```
@(1)[0..-1]
```

Which, from an array of a single `1` gives the following output

```
1 
1
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It's a shame though that you can use negative indexing but it is not implemented in ranges; it is unnatural and frustrating.

Comment: `[1,2,3,4][1..-1]` in Ruby results in `[2,3,4]`. `@(1,2,3,4)[1..-1]` in Powershell results in `2,1,4`. The issue with `-1` in Powershell is not only about duplicates.

Answer (score 10):

There might be a situation where you are processing a list, but you don't know the length.  Select-object has a -skiplast parameter.

```
(1,2,3,4,5 | select -skiplast 2)

1
2
3
```

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned earlier the best solution here:
`$array[0..($array.length - 2)]`

The problem you met with `$array[0..-2]` can be explained with the nature of `"0..-2"` expression and the range operator `".."` in PowerShell. If you try to evaluate just this part `"0..-2"` in PowerShell you will see that result will be an array of numbers from 0 to -2.

```
>> 0..-2
0
-1
-2
```

And when you're trying to do `$array[0..-2]` in PowerShell it's the same as if you would do `$array[0,-1,-2]`. That's why you get results as `1, 5, 4` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4`.

It could be kind of counterintuitive at first especially if you have some Python or Ruby background, but you need to take it into account when using PowerShell.

Answer (score 2):

Robert Westerlund answer is excellent.
This answer I just saw on the [Everything you wanted to know about arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-arrays) page and wanted to try it out.
I like it because it seems to describe exactly what the goal is, end at one short of the upper bound.

```
$array[0..($array.GetUpperBound(0) - 1)]
1
2
3
4
```

I used this variation of your original attempt to uninstall all but the latest version from Get-InstalledModule. It's really short, but not perfect because if there are more than 9 items it still returns just 8, but you can put a larger negative number, though.

```
$array[-9..-2]
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I had no idea .GetUpperBound(0) existed. `.GetUpperBound(0) - 1` is so much more intuitive than `.Count - 2`, even if it is longer.